# Planarity Criterion

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am looking for a proof of the theorem:

If a planar graph, $G$, has $v$ vertices ($v \geq 3$) and no cycles of length 3 then, $e \leq 2v-4$.

I remember doing this in a graph theory course and I think we used Euler's Formula $v-e+f =2$ but I forget how exactly.

Any reference or solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Euler's formula, $v-e+f=2.$

None of the faces are triangles (so each face has at least four edges) and every edge is in exactly two faces, so $2e \geq 4f.$

Combining these results we get $v-e+\frac{e}{2} \geq 2,$ which can be rearranged to give the desired result.